# Convert Hex Data in an Image Field to String

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

We have a database hosted on our SQL Server 2016 server that has email content stored in an `IMAGE` type column. I am trying to convert the data to its string representation. Everything I've read says that I should be able to just use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), Field, 1)` but that's not working. I've tried the following as a test:

```
declare @body varbinary(max);

select @body = substring(cast(body as varbinary(max)),1,13) from dbo.arc_bodies where id = -2147467502

select @body, convert(varchar(1000), @body, 1), convert(varchar(1000), 0x3C68746D6C3E)
```

So I take the first 13 bytes (just for testing I kept the data short instead of grabbing the whole column) from the "body" IMAGE field and convert it to `VARBINARY`. In the last statement, I show the contents of `@body`, try the convert, and try the convert by just copying the raw data.

This is what I end up with:

```
(No column name)                (No column name)                (No column name)
0x3C68746D6C3E0D0A3C68656164    0x3C68746D6C3E0D0A3C68656164    <html>
```

The convert of the @body returns the exact same data as the raw binary but the convert of the raw data works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And the expected result is?

Comment: You need to know exactly what is stored in your column in order to do anything with it. And then you need to understand how you actually intend to use it. Typically you don't convert an image to string - that simply creates a string representation of the binary (as hex) digits. It sounds like your image contains some sort of structure in which an image is embedded perhaps? You may need to track down how this content is stored in the database initially to understand how to work with it.

Comment: If it's already binary - ***WHY*** do you want to convert it to a string? It'll take up a lot more space, and I don't really see any benefit of doing that. You **SHOULD** change the column's datatype to `VARBINARY(MAX)` - since `IMAGE` has been deprecated for a long time and is bound to be removed in one of the next versions of SQL Server ....

Comment: @jarlh-The expected result would be <html>, the same as the last column.

Comment: @Smor-This application hex encodes the bodies of emails and puts it in to an IMAGE type field.  Why an IMAGE field?  I have no idea.  Really it should be a VARBINARY field but I didn't develop the application or DB.  I'm just trying to access the data.

Comment: @marc_s-This is not my application.  I am just trying to get at the email body text that they are storing in the IMAGE field.  Unfortunately, I can't change the data type because it's not my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3rd column in the last query you don't use any style. Just do the same for the 2nd one:

```
select @body, convert(varchar(1000), @body), convert(varchar(1000), 0x3C68746D6C3E)
```

[A reference to MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#binary-styles)

Comment: Well I'll be damned.  That worked.  Everything I had seen said that you need to specify the style in the conversion (either 1 or 2).  I never tried it without it.  Kind of kicking myself over not thinking about this.  I've spent way more time on this than I want to admin.  Thanks!